# event.srcElement.value equivalent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function that is written in `javascript` and I want to rewrite that in `jQuery` This is the function code:

```
function onclickRbtn(controlID , Message)
     {
         var s = document.getElementById(controlID);
         var sVal = event.srcElement.value;
         for (var i = 0; i < s.rows.length; i++)
          {
             if (s.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value == sVal)
                 s.getElementsByTagName("label")[i].innerText = Message;
         }
         s.disabled = 'disabled';
    }
```

What is this code :event.srcElement.value` and what is equivalent in jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: This is the most direct answer regardless of the re-write of the rest of the function which makes sense because you were asking specifically about jQuery.

Comment: This is logical refactoring-in of the following concepts:

1) In jQuery 1.9 the depreciated (and removed) srcElement attribute is replaced by "target", so "event.srcElement.value" goes to "event.target.value".

2) In jQuery you can go straight to the value by using "$(this).val()" in the context of an event handler, i.e. your click function declaration.

3) One of the main benefits of jQuery is to cut down on subroutines by using delegate functions on selectors like ".on()", ".click()", etc...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [***event.target***](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

To find out which element is the target of the event you can use

[***http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target***](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target)

Answer (score 3):

If you have working JavaScript code, DO NOT rewrite it in jQuery. That's like saying "this hammer can push nails into a wall, but I want to use a sledgehammer instead."

That aside, the code you have is exclusive to IE 8 and below, it won't work in IE 9 or other browsers, because it uses specific terms (global `event` object, `srcElement`...)

Here's the code you should use:

```
function onclickRbtn(controlID,Message,evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var s = document.getElementById(controlID),
        sVal = (evt.srcElement || evt.target).value,
        inputs = s.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        labels = s.getElementsByTagName('label');

    for( var i=0; i<s.rows.length; i++) {
        if( inputs[i].value == sVal) labels[i].innerText = labels[i].textContent = Message;
    }
    s.disabled = true;
}
```

And wherever you attach the event, make sure you add the event to the arguments. Examples:

```
<element onclick="onclickRbtn(controlID, Message, event);">
elem.onclick = function(e) {onclickRbtn(controlID, Message, e);};
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in IE9, IE 8, IE7, Chrome 22, Safari 5.7.1. It does not work in FF 14:

```
$(event.srcElement || event.target);
```